# Siddhi query for event prior to another within time limit

Tags: complex-event-processing, siddhi, stream-processing

I am trying to write a Siddhi query to detect if an event didn't happen prior to another within a time limit. The query I have to detect if 'X' didn't ever happen prior to 'Y' in the entire life of the siddhi application is:

```
from stream[value == 'Y']
and not stream[value == 'X']
```

I assumed adding a time constraint would work:

```
from stream[value == 'Y']
and not stream[value == 'X'] for 5 min
```

However, the 'for' statement never has any effect that I can see. This query is still triggered whether 'X' was 4 minutes ago or 6 minutes ago. I understand that a similar effect can be achieved by checking if 'Y' comes after 'X' within a time limit, but for my purposes I need to know the other way around.

Is this possible with Siddhi? If so can someone please provide a sample query that could achieve this?

Comment: I do not understand why "checking if 'Y' comes after 'X' within a time limit" does not achieve your requirement. It is the proper way to write this plus you will get the same result. Can you please explain?

Comment: @Tishan Because if X happens Y may or may not happen. But if Y happens X must have happened.

Comment: Yes I understand that. Yet you only need to identify if there is a 'X' prior to 'Y'. In other words for every 'Y' you need to check for a prior 'X' and if 'X' is there emit a result. If you can confirm above is the requirement we can do it using a pattern query. Upon confirmation Ill post an answer with a sample query

Comment: It might help if I explain the use case. We are trying to use Siddhi to loosely model a state machine by mostly using sequence queries. But to make sure a user doesn't enter the state machine at some random state in the middle, we need to verify for each state whether the previous state happened within some time limit. If our state machine is 'X' -> 'Y' then the only way we can verify they didn't start at 'Y' is making sure 'X' already happened.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment I am composing below answer.
[Sequence](https://wso2.github.io/siddhi/documentation/siddhi-4.0/#sequence) construct in Siddhi will guarantee that no one can enter the state flow at a random point. As an example let's take below sample sequence query.

```
from every e1=InputStream[state='X'], e2=InputStream[state'Y']
select e1.state as initialState, e2.state as finalState
insert into NextStream;
```

So in here we are mandating X followed by a consecutive Y. If Y occurs before X sequence construct will handle that and discard Y. So whatever goes into NextStream is guaranteed to satisfy x -> Y state transition.

More relaxed construct of sequence is [pattern](https://wso2.github.io/siddhi/documentation/siddhi-4.0/#pattern). It is same as sequence while relaxing the consecutive arrival requirement. Hope this helps!!